# The DNS server machine currently has no DNS domain name

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dns-server, windows-dns

I found the following message inside the DNS Server Event logs.

What I should do has been explained inside the message but not sure what exactly it means.

> Log Name:      DNS Server
>
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service
>
> Date:          14.08.2011 11:30:57
>
> Event ID:      414
>
> Task Category: None
>
> Level:         Warning
>
> Keywords:      Classic
>
> User:          N/A
>
> Computer:      WIN-EG75FS9C2F2
>
> Description:
>
> The DNS server computer currently does not have a DNS domain name. 
>   Its DNS name is a single-label host name with no domain (for example: 
>   "host" rather than "host.microsoft.com").
>
> You might have forgotten to configure a primary DNS domain for the
>   server computer.
>
> Because the DNS server has only a single-label name, all zones created
>   will have default records (SOA and NS) created using only this
>   single-label name for the server's host name.  This can lead to
>   incorrect and failed referrals when clients and other DNS servers use
>   these records to locate this server by name.
>
> To correct this problem:
>
> 1) Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
>
> 2) Open System and Maintenance , and then open System.
>
> 3) Click Change Settings, and then click Change.  4) Click either
>   Domain or Workgroup, and then type the name of the domain or 
>   workgroup you want the computer to join; the domain or workgroup name
>   will be used as your DNS domain name.
>
> 5) When prompted, restart the computer.
>
> After the computer restarts, the DNS server will attempt to fix up
>   default records, substituting the new DNS name of this server for the
>   old single-label name.  However, you should review the zone's SOA and
>   NS records to ensure that they now use the correct domain name of this
>   server.
>
> Event Xml:
>
> ```
> <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service"
> ```
>
> Guid="{guid-comes-here}" EventSourceName="DNS" />
>
> ```
> <EventID Qualifiers="32768">414</EventID>
>
> <Version>0</Version>
>
> <Level>3</Level>
>
> <Task>0</Task>
>
> <Opcode>0</Opcode>
>
> <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
>
> <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-08-14T08:30:57.000000000Z" />
>
> <EventRecordID>159</EventRecordID>
>
> <Correlation />
>
> <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
>
> <Channel>DNS Server</Channel>
>
> <Computer>MyComputerName</Computer>
>
> <Security />
> ```
>
> ```
> <Binary>
>
> </Binary>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Windows DNS will auto configure certain records based on whether your server has a FQDN or not. Example the NS and SOA and A record for the DNS server. Looks like you just installed the machine and the DNS role. You haven't given it a name other than the auto assigned WIN-EG75FS9C2F2 random name. Once you give it a FQDN like server.domain.com, DNS will be able to add records into any zones you create in DNS.

Comment: thanks. I am pretty new to this stuff. what should be the server.domain.com for me? should domain be my companies domain name? should server here be my server ip address? or anything I want.

Comment: Please provide some details of how you want to use the DNS. Is it going to host any zones or a caching server (which forwards elsewhere)? An example name of ns1.company.com would suffice where ns1 is your new server name and company.com is your company's domain. When choosing server names, obviously you shouldn't use a name already in use.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a new install of a DNS Server, run through the **DNS Server Wizard**:

1. Select **Start > Administrative Tools > DNS**.
2. Highlight your computer name and from the top choose **Action > Configure a DNS Server** to launch the **Configure DNS Server Wizard**.

[Tech Republic has a good run down of walking you through the wizard step by step.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-install-and-configure-a-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008/327)